# Create image in button

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I create an image in button. Instead of having text saying "Draw" I want it to be a picture of a brush.

Code:

```
self.draw_button = Button(self.root, text='Draw', command=self.use_draw) 
self.draw_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an image with tkinter's `PhotoImage` then set it inside Button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

img = PhotoImage(file='paint_brush.png')

draw_button = Button(root, image=img)
draw_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```